# merge several float and str objects into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am writing some Python code that calls a smart device API every 5 minutes and returns values 1 by 1.
The `t1me` object is `str` while the rest are `float`.

```
t1me = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.json()['data']['time']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
co2 = response.json()['data']['co2']
humidity = response.json()['data']['humidity']
pressure = response.json()['data']['pressure']
temp = response.json()['data']['temp']
voc = response.json()['data']['voc']

t1me
'2023-06-23 13:50:14'
co2
768.0
humidity
55.0
pressure
1003.3
temp
18.9
voc
46.0
```

I would like to merge the results into a simple dataframe like this so I can export it to Google Sheets:

| Datetime | Temp | Humidity | Pressure | CO2 | VOC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-23 13:50:14 | 18.9 | 55.0 | 1003.3 | 768.0 | 46.0 |

But I am not sure how to do this with pandas?
Probably could just call all the data in a single JSON request but not sure how to do that either.

Comment: How looks json `j = response.json()['data']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and convert column to datetime - if necessary string representation add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
j = response.json()['data']
df = pd.json_normalize(j)

#datetimes
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')

#strings, add if necessary
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: this works great! but I can't get the time value to convert. keep getting the error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?

Comment: @DrPaulVella - no, seems need `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: thanks but that only returned 1970-01-01 00:00:01 I did manage to get it to work with ````df['time'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.json()['data']['time']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")````

Comment: @DrPaulVella what is `print (df['time'].head().tolist())` before `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` ?

Comment: @DrPaulVella - Use `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')`